# Specifying the start and the end date of the trading

Tags: date, datetime, mql4, metatrader4, mt4

I just added the ability to specify the start and end date of the trading to my EA, however, I discovered a weird behaviour!

If I have specified the starting date for trade from
 **`2016.05.01 00:00:00`**
and the end date to
 **`2016.05.10 00:00:00`**
 the EA trades from `2015.05.02 00:00` to `2016.05.12 14:02`
 but if I specified the date from
`2016.06.01 00:00:00` to `2016.06.10 00:00:00`
 it trades from 
`2016.06.01 00:00` to `2016.06.10 14:53`

Here is my code:

```
   extern datetime StartDate = __DATETIME__;
   extern datetime EndDate   = __DATETIME__;

   int isTrading = 0;

   if (  StartDate < EndDate ) {
         if (  TimeCurrent() > StartDate
            && TimeCurrent() < EndDate
               ) isTrading = 1;
   } else {
         if (  TimeCurrent() > StartDate
            || TimeCurrent() < EndDate
               ) isTrading = 1;
   }
```

I don't know what is wrong here, any help will be much appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

### The simplest part:

Given the **`StartDate == 2016.05.01 00:00`**, there indeed the Market is closed ( and the call to **`TimeCurrent()`** function would return just some old `datetime` value from the last tick from the last week of April ).

As the Market is closed yet, no **`OnTick()`**-triggering event ( message ) will arrive ( the less any trading will ever be able to happen ) until **`2016.05.02`** ( Monday ) starts and the first "***new***" **`QUOTE`** message indeed arrives from the Server-side, based on some further details.

### Documentation warns:

> **`datetime  TimeCurrent();`**
>   Returns the last known server time, **time of the last quote receipt** for one of the symbols selected in the "Market Watch" window. In the **`OnTick()`** handler, this function returns the time of the received handled tick. In other cases ( for example, call in handlers `OnInit()`, `OnDeinit()`, `OnTimer()` and so on ) this is the time of the last quote receipt for any symbol available in the "Market Watch" window, the time shown in the title of this window. The time value is formed on a trade server and does not depend on the time settings on your computer.

---

### The few harder points:

- GMT-offset of the Broker Server-side setup ( not a problem in very this server-side / server-side `datetime` perspective, otherwise yes )
- FX-instrument ( `_Symbol` ) trading conditions ( Precious metals and Indices typically start with additional time-offsets and do not follow 24*5 Market Trading Hours of the Majors ).
- Broker-specific changes of trading hours / outages announced in advance.
- MetaTrader Terminal 4 [ Strategy Tester ] may behave surprisingly on incomplete data ( Gaps in History Centre ) and the documentation warns just "indirectly" about this:

  > During testing in the Strategy Tester, **`TimeCurrent()`** is simulated according to historical data.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, why it continues open trades untile it reaches to `2016.05.12 14:02` not `2016.05.10`?

Comment: Hard to say, given just an incomplete MCVE-code is shown. Would you mind to post the complete code, the _Symbol you test the code against, your localhost TimeZone location + your Broker Server- TimeZone, the _Symbol Terms & Conditions ( namely the Market  ( pre-Market / post-Market ) hours ) as were set by the Broker?

Comment: Sure, the broker is XM, the server is XM.COM-Demo, currency EURUSD, I only run the test in the "Strategy Tester", however my EA is too big and I think I'll  sell it so I can't publish its code but I'll tell you what I programmed it to do just for the sake of the test that I did, it just sell, and must have one position only, so when the position get close the EA immediately open a new sell position.

Comment: If I set the starting date to trade to `2016.07.05 00:00:00` and the end date to `2016.07.10 00:00:00` it trades from `2016.07.05 00:00:00` to 2016.07.12 10:19